# c++ how to shrink std::vector to a subselection efficiently

Tags: c++, vector, move

given two vectors

```
std::vector<SomeStruct> items;  //1'000'000 items
std::vector<int> selection;  //900'000 unique indices in ascending order
```

where `selection` contains valid indices into `items`, how can I shrink `items` efficiently to only contain the elements that are initially indexed by `selection`?

Comment: Are the elements in `selection` sorted? Which meaning of efficiently do you mean? Do you want to minimize memory, complexity or maximize readability?

Comment: did you try something? I would create a new vector, perhaps use `std::transform` with a `std::back_inserter` to populate it, but essentially its just a simple loop. I would not erase elements from `items` because I'd expect that to be very costly

Comment: what are the sizes of the vectors? Are there more elements in `selection` or more elements to be removed?

Comment: I would also consider to not modify `items` at all, but use a custom iterator that allows to access those elements in `items` that are present in `selection`. It really depends on the boundary conditions and what you mean with "efficient"

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux by efficient I mean preferrably something that internally uses move semantics, so that if SomeStruct contains for example elements with expensive copy constructors, no unnecessary copies are generated

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number both a few hundred thousands. selection maybe 90% of items. selection is guaranteed to contain indices in ascending order and to contain each index only once

Comment: please edit the question to add those details

Comment: Since the index vector is sorted, just iterate over it. Setup an iterator to the beginning of the data vector (the "other iterator"). For each element in the index vector, move the element at that position in the data vector with the element referred to by the other iterator, and increment the other iterator. Then shrink the vector by erasing every element at and after the other iterator's final value. This works if the index are in order, you don't need to preserve any elements before the index currently being inspected.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to write this answer in reverse. Bear with me, I hope you will understand.

Lets first write a wrapper that lets us iterate only selected items:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct SomeStruct {};

struct selected_item {
    std::vector<SomeStruct>& items;
    std::vector<size_t>& selection;
    struct iterator {
        std::vector<SomeStruct>& items;
        std::vector<size_t>::iterator selection_iterator;
        SomeStruct& operator *(){
            return items[*selection_iterator];
        }
        iterator& operator++(){
            ++selection_iterator;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& other){
            return selection_iterator != other.selection_iterator;
        }
    };
    iterator begin() { return {items,selection.begin()}; }
    iterator end() { return {items,selection.end()};}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<SomeStruct> items{{},{},{},{}};
    std::vector<size_t> selection{1,3};
    for (auto& i : selected_item{items,selection}){
        std::cout << "item selected\n";
    }
}
```

Using that you can now write a loop that moves selected items from `items` into a new vector, then move that new vector into items:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<SomeStruct> items{{},{},{},{}};
    std::vector<size_t> selection{1,3};
    std::vector<SomeStruct> temp_items;
    temp_items.reserve(selection.size());
    for (auto& i : selected_item{items,selection}){
       temp_items.emplace_back(std::move(i));
    }
    items = std::move(temp_items);
}
```

Supposed `SomeStruct` can be moved, this will not copy any `SomeStruct`. However, also moving is not for free. Depending on why you actually want to remove elements from `items` (why not populate a vector of selected items in the first place, instead of populating a vector of indices?) you can also consider to skip the moving altogether and use only the above wrapper to do whatever you want to do with the selected items. As 90% of the items are selected, it might be that the savings in memory and more efficient element access (due to a smaller vector) does not outweigh the moving, so you might as well directly do:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<SomeStruct> items{{},{},{},{}};
    std::vector<size_t> selection{1,3};
    for (auto& i : selected_item{items,selection}){
       do_something_with_selected_item(i);
    }
    
}
```

Another option would be to actually erase elements from `items`. I did not consider it because I expect it to be rather costly. I might be wrong about that. As always, to know what is more efficient you need to measure.

PS: The wrapper is tested with gcc. I find it a little annoying to write custom iterators, not sure if it needs eg an `operator==` or a post-increment. I only implemented what was necessary to make gcc happy.